# How to see a portfolio's overall profit or loss on Yahoo Finance?

Tags: investing, portfolio, yahoo-finance, profitability

On Yahoo Finance, I created  a sample portfolio and added a few stocks.

Now when I go to the portfolio, it shows me the current price, how much up and down since the previous day, volume, etc.

But what I am interested in is to see the **percentage profit or loss** since I bought the stock. Is there a way to see that, similar to what I can see with my brokerage account?  What steps are involved?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the settings to see what the portfolio displays to see if it could provide you this data?  In particular the "Performance" tab on the portfolio page?

Answer (score 3):

The steps that I could imagine following:

1. ["My Portfolios"](http://finance.yahoo.com/portfolio/pf_1/view/v1) tab on Yahoo Finance is a starting point.
2. Click on the "Performance" tab, where Basic is the default selection.
3. Click on the "Add/Edit Holdings" so that a cost basis can be determined as you need to know this to determine whether or not you've gained or lost since you bought the stock.
4. Click the "Save" button and return back to the "Performance" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Geez, it has been ages since I used the Yahoo Finance portfolio.  Anyway, I just opened it up and it's still as clunky as ever.

If you don't have a portfolio, create one.  Enter your holdings. Then click on My Holdings and it will display the percent gain/loss of each position as well as the total gain (or loss) in dollars.